# Product Attributes that do not require product variations

Tags: commerce

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have product attributes that do not require individual SKUs and do not have to be entered as product variations.  My use case is this:  We are selling dinners with three different entrees and three different desserts.  We do not need to charge different amounts for each combination, but we do need to know how many of each have been ordered.  I can make this work by creating a separate product variation for each combination, but is there an easier way??

I have looked at commmerce_pricing_attributes and commerce_option but the project pages for these modules say that they only work with D7.

I am running commerce 8.x-2.24 on version 9.2.4 of Drupal

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for aren't attributes as Drupal Commerce considers them. Using your example as a model, we'd say the "product" being sold is the dinner and the precise entree / dessert selections are customizations or options of the underlying product (a nice dinner : ).

The way to accommodate these is to use order item fields that are exposed to the Add to Cart form. This is a bit simpler in Commerce 2.x, as Drupal core added form modes, so you should find what you ned in the field management interface for your order item type.

If the site sells other kinds of products, bear in mind that you have the freedom to create as many order item types as you need and just need to associate them properly from different product types.